# How can I delete certain characters in a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, truncate

For example, if i'm taking in the string below.

```
"{{((A+b)-xyz)addf}sss}";
```

I would like to ignore all characters that aren't a parenthesis or curly bracket, resulting.

```
"{{(())}}"
```

What method would be most efficient to do.

Comment: You could either read that to buffer and copy-append only the desired characters to another `std::string`, or read `char` by `char` and discard undesired characters. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Look into std::regex or QRegularExpression etc.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't specify how exactly you obtain the string, but considering:

```
std::string str = "{{((A+b)-xyz)addf}sss}";
```

You could use the `erase-remove` idiom. We specify a custom deleter, which will be a function (actually a lambda - a functor) that will check for a character not being a curly bracket or a parenthesis.

```
auto deleter = [](const char c){
    return c != '(' && c != ')' && c != '{' && c != '}';
};
```

Then we use `erase-remove` idiom:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), deleter), str.end());
```

This will result in the original `str` turning into: `{{(())}}`.